# Font size distorts when resizing

Tags: css, font-size, responsive

I have a small bug in a website I'm working on.
a specific div contains a paragraph tag. this P tag has a font size for small screens and a bigger font size for big screens. here is the problem. When I resize the browser using the mouse the sizes changes correctly. but if I resize to the small screen and not back step by step by the mouse but by clicking the maximize button ( at the top right ) then again click the same button to back to the small screen the font sizes don't change to the small and all the fonts are so big. is there a solution?

Comment: Can you share an example of your issue with the corresponding code?

Comment: here is a link to the site https://www.xlash.com/

Comment: fix the 86 errors in your html https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xlash.com%2F

Comment: hm, thanks for helping